# How to hook after `res.send` but before the response leaves the server, ==> when res.statusCode is know

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I already use the *middleware* facility in **Express.js** by means of `app.use()` to hook on all requests and log a message, but found the fact that `res.statusCode` is nearly always **200**, which I checked is not correct. I presume this is the default value and since it is not yet replaced with my own `statusCode` with `res.send(204)` well, is always **200**.

I know I can log the message after every `res.send(x)` in every request, but as you might imagine, that is cumbersome.

So, the question is:

**Where/How can I hook my middleware function with the conditions that is only in one place and `res.statusCode` is the one that the client really sees?**

**Relevant code:**

```
// Log API requests.
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    logger.info('API request.', {
        module: 'core'
        data  : {
            req: {
                method: req.method,
                url   : req.url,
                ip    : req.ip
            },
            res: {
                status_code: res.statusCode // Always 200 and not the really one.
            }
        }
    });

    next();
});

app.use(app.router);
```

If I move `app.use(app.router)` the middleware don't get executed.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`res` inherits from `http.ServerResponse` [in the standard library](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse).  This means that it is an `EventEmitter` with a `finish` event.  So in your middleware, register for the `finish` event and do the logging when that fires:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.on('finish', function() {
        logger.info('API request.', {
            module: 'core'
            data  : {
                req: {
                    method: req.method,
                    url   : req.url,
                    ip    : req.ip
                },
                res: {
                    status_code: res.statusCode
                }
            }
        });
    });

    next();
});
```

You could, of course, register with `res.once`, but the `finish` event is guaranteed to fire only once, so that shouldn't be necessary unless there's a bug in the standard library.

This won't necessarily occur "after `res.send` but before the response leaves the server" as you request - the docs on the `finish` event only claim that

> [T]his event is emitted when the last segment of the response headers and body have been handed off to the operating system for transmission over the network.

So, some of the response may have already left the server.  However, I believe it is the closest you'll get without monkey-patching `express`, which I would advise against.

Comment: Neat! Worked like a charm. Thanks!